# Why operator systems?

Tags: reference-request, fa.functional-analysis, oa.operator-algebras, hilbert-spaces

A $\mathrm{C}^*$-algebra $\mathcal{A}\subset B(\mathsf{H})$ is a norm-closed, self-adjoint subalgebra of bounded operators on a Hilbert space. If we then take a unital self-adjoint (possibly closed) subspace (not subalgebra) we have an *operator system* $\mathcal{O}\subset \mathcal{A}$.

(I am aware there are abstract definitions of both $\mathrm{C}^*$-algebras and operator systems).

My question is:

> *Why are operator systems studied?*

I presume that they are not studied for their own sake. I have tried to find the answer to this question by skimming papers, but to no avail. All I can distill is that perhaps they can help study $\mathrm{C}^*$-algebras, either their $\mathrm{C}^*$-envelopes, or perhaps their ambient $\mathrm{C}^*$-algebras $\mathcal{A}\supset \mathcal{O}$. Perhaps they are studied to learn about completely positive maps, the appropriate morphisms of operator systems.

I would have thought they are not coming from a physics motivation: from my point of view the algebra structure for observables makes more sense than the vector structure. I have asked this question in that context [here](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/728432/operator-systems-vs-operator-algebras). If the motivation is well addressed in some paper, I would be happy to be pointed to such a reference.

There is one MO user who I think I could email this question to directly but that would be rather presumptive on my part.

Comment: I (group theorist) came to realize the usefulness of operator systems when I saw the result of Kalantar-Kennedy https://arxiv.org/abs/1405.4359, relating the Hamana boundary (an operator system concept) with the Furstenberg boundary (topological concept), thus shading light on the problem of group C*-simplicity.

Comment: I am by no means a specialist but seemingly e. g. the fact that injective operator systems carry a conditionally complete C*-algebra structure looks like a quite strong result, no? It must be easier to understand such algebras when you know that you can recapture them from the underlying operator system alone...

Comment: A closely related, also I think quite strong result by Choi and Effros (1977): any unit preserving complete order-isomorphism between unital C*-algebras is a *-algebra isomorphism.

Comment: This is far from the only reason, but see the paper https://arxiv.org/abs/2004.14115 by Connes and van Suijlekom for a discussion of operator systems in the context of non commutative geometry (with physical applications in mind).

Comment: To appeal to authority, Grothendieck is purported to have said ``It is better to have a good category with bad objects than a bad category with good objects". The category of unital completely positive maps and operator systems is much versatile than that of *-homomorphisms and C*-algebras which is too rigid. For example, finite-dimensional operator subsystems exhaust the ambient C*-algebra, and there are always plenty of unital completely positive maps between any operator systems.

Comment: Thank you all so much for your contributions. I will leave the question another while and if there is no answer at that point I may make a community wiki answer out of your comments.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Collating some comments, it appears that one reason why operator systems are studied is because they are *useful*:

- Uri Bader mentions [a paper of Kalantar & Kennedy](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1405.4359.pdf) which makes extensive use of Hamana's theory for injective envelopes for operator systems equipped with a group action.
- მამუკა ჯიბლაძე explains that conditional complete C*-algebras may be recovered from their underling injective operator system, and so the underlying operator system may be used to study the algebra.
- t.c. points to [a paper of Connes & van Suijlekom](https://arxiv.org/pdf/2004.14115.pdf), where an operator systems approach to noncommutative geometry is explored, and t.c. suggests that this approach has physical applications in mind.

Of a slightly different bent, Narutaka OZAWA alludes to the question "*what are the appropriate morphisms for a category of C$^*$-algebras?*", and suggests that a usual choice is too rigid, something which is not the case for the category of operator systems.

Answer (score 4):

I just ran across this slightly older question. For me, operator systems are interesting because they can be thought of as "quantum graphs". This comes from the correspondence
$$\{1, \ldots,n\} \leftrightarrow \mathbb{C}^n$$
$$\mbox{relation on }\{1, \ldots, n\} \leftrightarrow \mbox{subspace $V$ of }M_n(\mathbb{C})$$
$$\mbox{reflexive relation}\leftrightarrow I \in V$$
$$\mbox{symmetric relation}\leftrightarrow V = V^*$$
$$\mbox{transitive relation}\leftrightarrow V^2 \subseteq V$$
etc., together with the dictum "a graph is a set equipped with a symmetric, reflexive relation".

This is just an analogy, but there is a broader theoretical framework that includes this "pure quantum" setup and a "pure classical" setup which is the usual familiar one, as special cases.

"So what?" you may ask. My answer is: this analogy allows us to import classical intuition into the quantum setting. It suggests natural questions. For instance: is there a "quantum" Ramsey theorem for finite dimensional operator systems? The answer is [yes](https://arxiv.org/abs/1601.01259). There is a "quantum" version of Turan's problem of determining the minimal number of edges that ensure a $k$-clique, or the maximal number of edges that ensure a $k$-anticlique, which was studied [here](https://arxiv.org/abs/1802.07394).

The broad theoretical framework I mentioned above is developed [here](https://arxiv.org/abs/1506.03892). The idea of operator systems as "quantum graphs" originally arose in the quantum error correction literature, in [this](https://arxiv.org/abs/1002.2514) paper, which showed that there is an operator system version of Lovasz's theta function for graphs.

Comment: Lovely answer thank you. Small question: why do you want a graph to be reflexive? I would have said a graph is a symmetric IRreflexive relation.

Comment: Excellent question! This point of view came out of quantum error correction. In classical error correction you make a graph whose vertices are all possible signals, with an edge between two signals if they are sufficiently close that after a minor transmission error they could be confused. (It's called the "confusability graph".) In this context it's clear why you want an edge from every vertex to itself.

Comment: Here's another illustration. Any equivalence relation on a set can be turned into a graph by putting an edge between two vertices if they are equivalent. So a related question is why we take equivalence relations to be reflexive and not irreflexive?

Comment: The bottom line is that the theory of quantum graphs works more smoothly if you follow this convention.

Comment: Thank you, the confusability matrix part makes sense alright.